# multiprocessing inside async in python 3.8 fails (Can't pickle local object)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-3.8

The following code does work in python 3.7, but it doesn't work in python 3.8 (`AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.f'`)

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import asyncio

async def main():
    def f():
        print("hello")

    p = mp.Process(target=f)
    p.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I know that running a process inside an async function is not a common thing and might raise a few eyebrows, but I've found it useful sometimes. What is the reason it doesn't work in python 3.8 anymore? Is there a way to update the code to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

I just realized that this has nothing to do with async. It fails without async too. The fix was to move `f` outside of `main`. Not sure why this is now required in python 3.8 though.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import asyncio

def f():
    print("hello")

async def main():
    p = mp.Process(target=f)
    p.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I think easier and more clean solution is to make it a Class?

Comment: @jacobgalam Python is not Java, it is totally fine to use free-standing functions. The problem with the original code was that the function was defined locally, so it couldn't be transferred to the subprocess.

Comment: yepp, this is not documented in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py), but the target function must be global. ideally someone should fix the docs...